# Is it possible to not sample some traces in AWS X Ray?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-xray

Is it possible to not sample some traces in X Ray?

I am not interested in traces that begin with `/foo/` url so I set up a Sampling Rule with the following settings:

```
URL Matches: `/foo/*`
ReservoirSize: 0
FixedRate: 0
priority: 100
```

Everything else I left to the default value. What I expect to happen is for all new traces to no longer appear, but when I go to the Traces tab, I can still see traces when I search for:

`http.url BEGINSWITH "/foo/"` for the past 5 minutes

I created the sampling rule 5 days ago. I do not have any other sampling rule except for the default one which has priority 10000 (which means my new rule should take priority).

I expect there to no longer be any traces whose url starts with `/foo/`. Is there something I'm missing here? Is it even possible to set ReservoirSize=0 and FixedRate=0 at the same time?

Comment: same issue looks like 0 is ignored